# Why does JLink lock unopened jar-files in Windows

Tags: java

Since the introduction of `JLink` (maybe a bit later) it is possible to put jar libraries inside the directory-structure of packages. If this package is installed in one of the places Mathematica searches, the jar libraries are automatically found by `JLink`.

The problem is that under 64 bit Windows XP, after loading `JLink` these files are locked and cannot be removed from within Mathematica, although none of the jars are really used, but only added to the class-path of Java.

Let me give a short example: Place a `Test` folder with `Java` subfolder inside your `$UserAddOnsDirectory` and copy any jar file into the `Java` folder. This looks like

```
Test/
└── Java
    └── blub.jar
```

When you now start a fresh Kernel and load `` <<JLink` `` you can verify by looking at `JavaClassPath[]`, that this directory and the jar was indeed added to the class-path. When you try to remove the complete folder, you get (a misleading) error message

```
DeleteDirectory[path, DeleteContents -> True]

(*
    DeleteDirectory::dirne: Directory D:\Documents and Settings\mscheibe\
    Application Data\Mathematica\Applications\Test not empty. >>
*)
```

After `Quit`-ing the kernel, calling `UninstallJava[]` or `` JLink`QuitJava[] `` the directory can be removed. This behavior does not occur in Linux or on MacOSX and I could only test it on `Windows XP 64 bit`.

**Question:** Why, if the jar-path is only appended to the class-path, does `JLink` lock the files as they where opened for reading? Why does this happen on `Windows` only? Is there anyone, who has a deeper insight into `JLink` who can suggest a better solution that calling `` JLink`QuitJava[]; Pause[2]; `` inside my module when I want to remove a jar-file found by Mathematica.

**Remark 1:** This behavior is not restricted to automatically found jars. When you use java-code by manually adding a jar with `AddToClassPath[path]` the similar thing happens.

**Remark 2:** I forgot to mention, that `` JLink`QuitJava[] `` does not really quit java like `Quit` would kill the kernel. Meaning, I call this and *without* doing anything else I can still call my functions inside the jars. This seems to suggest, that `QuitJava[]` kills the class-loader instance Leonid is mentioning which locks the files. But a call to e.g. `JavaNew` seems to set up everything correct again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I also encountered this problem. Not an authoritative answer, but here is one blind guess to what is happening. JLink has its own classloader, `JLinkClassLoader.java`, which calls another one, `JLinkClassLoaderHelper.java`. The latter is a sub-class of `URLClassLoader.java`. Both are used in the class `JLinkSystemClassLoader.java`. The second part of this story is that there is an [unresolved bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=5041014) in the JVM related to `URLClassLoader.java` class, which locks jars, on Windows only. It has been discussed on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216780/problem-reloading-a-jar-using-urlclassloader). The problem seems to be Windows-specific. What I don't know is at what time this happens, and why this affects jars that weren't even used. If this is at all a right guess, this can probably be traced by using a debugger.

Comment: +1 This seems to explain, why you can break the lock with `QuitJava`. Does this mean that, when I have a few million jars in my search-path, JLink` opens and maybe loads every jar at startup instead of adding it to the search path? Does java has to preload jars or could it just start loading, when a symbol cannot be resolved?

Comment: @halirutan To answer this, I'd need to have a deeper understanding of the dynamics of class loading in JLink. I think however, that if/when this becomes a real problem, one can try to get a hold on the specific instance of `URLClassloader` (well, its J/Link subclass) created by JLink. In the JDK7, a new method `close` has been added to it, so I suppose it can be used explicitly from JLink/Mathematica, when you are done loading classes. Then, if you need to load more, you create a new instance. Something like that may work, but for that a full understanding of the process may be needed.

Comment: @halirutan From a cursory look at it, here is a work-around I'd suggest: 1. Subclass the `JLinkClassloader` class, making a field `helper` (of type `JLinkClassLoaderHelper`) public (it is protected in `JLinkClassloader`, which creates a singleton). 2. Work directly with the `KernelLink.java` class, which has a method `setClassLoader`: create an instance of `KernelLink`, and then set as the classloader the subclass I mentioned. 3. When needed, access the field `helper` of this subclass, and call `close()` on it. Then replace it with a new instance of the helper. No idea if this works though.

Comment: @halirutan Here is a link which may be of interest: http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v7/JLink/ref/java/com/wolfram/jlink/JLinkClassLoader.html